# Unable to find element with Xpath Selenium in IE

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

DOM Explorer of the object :

```
<INPUT tabIndex=0 onkeyup=DisableEnableFields(); onblur=autoValidate(this) id=prvd_org_name onkeydown="return HandleMaxLengths(this, 70,event,'','');" maxLength=70 size=120 name=prvd_org_name isRequired="false" ValidationType="ALPHANUMERICSPACEPUNCTUATION">
```

Please help me with the xpath

Tried below xpaths :

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name ='prvd_org_name']"))
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type= text and @name ='prvd_org_name']"))
```

Please gimme different alternatives as for the above two it gives me unable to find element

Comment: where and what are you trying to find?

Comment: <INPUT tabIndex=0 onkeyup=DisableEnableFields(); onblur=autoValidate(this) id=prvd_org_name onkeydown="return HandleMaxLengths(this, 70,event,'','');" maxLength=70 size=120 name=prvd_org_name isRequired="false" ValidationType="ALPHANUMERICSPACEPUNCTUATION">

Comment: could you share url of the page? Now looks like this page has invalid html: should be `name="prvd_org_name"`, not `name=prvd_org_name`

Answer (score 0):

To identify the element you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- `cssSelector`:

  ```
  WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input#prvd_org_name[name='prvd_org_name']"));
  ```
- `xpath`:

  ```
  WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='prvd_org_name' and @name='prvd_org_name']"));
  ```

However, as the element is a dynamic element so to identify the element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48989049/selenium-how-selenium-identifies-elements-visible-or-not-is-is-possible-that-i/48990165#48990165) for the `elementToBeClickable()` and you can use either of the following *Locator Strategies*:

- `cssSelector`:

  ```
  WebElement element = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("input#prvd_org_name[name='prvd_org_name']")));
  ```
- `xpath`:

  ```
  WebElement element = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//input[@id='prvd_org_name' and @name='prvd_org_name']")));
  ```